# Kinks in my valid expression checker

Tags: c++, validation, stack

So clearly I'm having some trouble with my valid expression operator. In theory, I understand the concept of checking for scope openers first and if you see a scope closer without a scope opener, then it is invalid. I'm not too sure if its the diagrams Ive drawn or what but still, like i said, I'm just a little confused when it comes to putting the algorithm to use when coding, any tips? Also,  My professor told me to use case switch here? Exactly how would that benefit me? Wouldn't I need 3 different case switches for both scope openers and closers when in reality all i need is an if statement?

```
 //=============use case switch here
    void check_expression(char expression[80], bool& valid)
    {
        Stack symbStack;  //stack to hold scope openers
        char symbol, //current symbol in the expression being investigated
        top_symb;  //current scope opener at the top of the stack
        int i = 0; //subscript to element in expression array, initialized to
                   //first element 

        valid = true;  
        symb = expression[i];
        while(symb != '\0') //while symbol in expression is not the null terminator
        {
                if( symbol == '{' || symbol == '[' || symbol == '(' )
                {
                    symbStack.Push(symbol);
                }

                else if( symbol == '}' || symbol == ']' || symbol == ')' )
                {
                    if(symbStack.IsEmpty())
                    {
                        cout << "Expression is invalid!";
                        valid == false;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        top_symb = symbStack.StackTop();
                        symbStack.Pop();

                        if(  (top_symb == '(' && symbol != ')') ||  
                             (top_symb == '[' && symbol != ']') ||
                             (top_symb == '{' && symbol != '}')   )
                        {
                            valid = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                i++;  //incrememt the subscript to the next character in the expression.
                symb = expression[i]; //assign symb to the next character in expression.
        }

        //Check to see if the stack is not empty.  If it is not empty, then 
        //the expression is invalid, in which case you want to assign valid to false
        return;
    }
```

Comment: *"I'm having some trouble with my valid expression operator"* And what those problems are? You provided some code, but it's not clear whether the problem is that it's broken and you ask how to fix it, or it's that your prof doesn't like it and you want us to explain his requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
valid == false;
     ^^^^
```

There's your culprit. Get rid of one of those `=` and you should be good.

As a sidenote, if you realize you're looking at an invalid expression, you can return immediately! There's no way for an expression to turn valid after that. So you can add `return;` after you set `valid` to `false`.